# Block Element Modifier - Using BEM without the 'Element'?

Tags: html, css, bem

While I have been working with CSS (and other CSS pre-processors) for a while, I am still not entirely confident when it comes to following the [Block Element Modifier (BEM) convention](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/).

Let's assuming we are following this particular BEM format:

```
block-name__element-name_modifier-name_modifier-value
```

May I know if it is acceptable to specify a class without the `element-name`? This means we only have the block, followed by the modifier.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="menu_light-theme">
  <!-- the other menu elements such as the buttons and icons -->
  <ul class="menu__list_light-theme>
    <li><a class="menu__list-element" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__list-element" href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above block of code, the `.menu_light-theme` class acts as a 'wrapper' for the menu, and the class name contains only the **block** and **modifier**.

I understand this is subjective, but I am wondering if this conforms to BEM, and of course, I open to suggestions on how I could handle such situations when the **element** of BEM may seem 'redundant'.

Comment: BEM is just a guideline, you can follow it to whatever degree works best for you

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, it's actually in the [documentation](http://getbem.com/introduction/):

```
.button--state-success {...}
```

In your example, we could do something like this (don't forget to put two dashes for the modifier):

```
<div class="menu--light-theme">
  <!-- the other menu elements such as the buttons and icons -->
  <ul class="menu__list--light-theme>
    <li><a class="menu__list-element" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu__list-element" href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts, mate! Oh, I didnt know the above documentation exist. Thanks for the link! It seems more concise than the one I have been following (https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation (http://getbem.com/naming/) we can use modifier on block or element but we have to keep class name of this block or element in html:

Good:

```
<div class="block block--modifier">
      <div class="block__element block__element--some-modifier">...</div>
      ...
</div>
```

Bad:

```
<div class="block--mod">...</div>
/* or */
<div class="block__element--mod">...</div>
```